# How to make the content of the web-page update automatically in the Node-RED?

Tags: javascript, node-red

How to make the node content dynamic?

The flow I have created has four nodes: http in, function, template, and http response.

The flow displays on the web page by the address `127.0.0.1/testcase` or `yourhost/testcase` three windows showing numbers. The first one is the current time seconds generated in the template node. The two other windows are supposed to display in real time the number generate in the function node of the flow.

They are being generated every second (you can see by adding debug node after function node). However, the values do not update **automatically**. To update it is needed to update manually the page: the values update.

Here is the node-RED flow to better see the case:

```
[
{
    "id": "d67de8615ea3d3a0",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "Flow 2",
    "disabled": false,
    "info": "",
    "env": []
},
{
    "id": "9777c31bb0ed4db4",
    "type": "http response",
    "z": "d67de8615ea3d3a0",
    "name": "",
    "statusCode": "200",
    "headers": {},
    "x": 760,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "ad9334b7892cf503",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "d67de8615ea3d3a0",
    "name": "Generate content",
    "func": "var date = new Date();\n\nvar inject = msg.payload;\n\nvar state = {};\n\n// generate some value and save it in the flow storage\nflow.set(\"variable\", Math.round(Math.round(10*Math.sin(date.getSeconds()))));\n\n// create some JSON \nstate[\"content\"] = {\n    \"time\": date.getSeconds(),\n    \"variable\": flow.get(\"variable\"),\n    \"inject\": inject\n};\n// handle it to a message payload\nmsg.payload = state;\nif (inject) {\n    return msg\n}\n",
    "outputs": 1,
    "timeout": 0,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 390,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": [
        [
            "652219a15a6b71e9"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "652219a15a6b71e9",
    "type": "template",
    "z": "d67de8615ea3d3a0",
    "name": "HTML",
    "field": "payload",
    "fieldType": "msg",
    "format": "handlebars",
    "syntax": "mustache",
    "template": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n    <style>\n        /* Center the window both vertically and horizontally */\n        body {\n            display: flex;\n            justify-content: center;\n            align-items: center;\n            height: 100vh;\n            margin: 0;\n            background-color: lightgrey; /* Background color of the page */\n        }\n\n        /* Style for the window */\n        #window {\n            width: 200px;\n            height: 100px;\n            background-color: lightblue; /* Blue color for the window */\n            border: 5px solid black; /* Black border */\n            border-radius: 10px;\n            display: flex;\n            justify-content: center;\n            align-items: center;\n            font-size: 36px;\n            font-weight: bold;\n            color: red; /* Red color for the text */\n        }\n        #window2 {\n            width: 200px;\n            height: 100px;\n            background-color: lightblue; /* Blue color for the window */\n            border: 5px solid black; /* Black border */\n            border-radius: 10px;\n            display: flex;\n            justify-content: center;\n            align-items: center;\n            font-size: 36px;\n            font-weight: bold;\n            color: red; /* Red color for the text */\n        }\n        #window3 {\n            width: 200px;\n            height: 100px;\n            background-color: lightblue; /* Blue color for the window */\n            border: 5px solid black; /* Black border */\n            border-radius: 10px;\n            display: flex;\n            justify-content: center;\n            align-items: center;\n            font-size: 36px;\n            font-weight: bold;\n            color: red; /* Red color for the text */\n        }\n    </style>\n</head>\n<body>\n    <div id=\"window\">\n        <span>var1</span> <!-- The var1 inside the window -->\n    </div>\n    <div id=\"window2\">\n        <span>var2</span> <!-- The var2 inside the window -->\n    </div>\n    <div id=\"window3\">\n        <span>var3</span> <!-- The var3 inside the window -->\n    </div>\n</body>\n<script>\n    function updateDynamicContent() {\n        var dynamicContent = document.getElementById('window');\n        var dynamicContent2 = document.getElementById('window2');\n        var dynamicContent3 = document.getElementById('window3');\n\n        var currentTime = new Date();\n                \n        dynamicContent.innerHTML = currentTime.getSeconds();\n        dynamicContent2.innerHTML = {{payload.content.time}};\n        dynamicContent3.innerHTML = {{payload.content.variable}};\n\t}\n\n\t// Use setInterval to call the updateDynamicContent function every second\n\tsetInterval(updateDynamicContent, 1000);\n</script>\n</html>\n\n",
    "output": "str",
    "x": 570,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": [
        [
            "9777c31bb0ed4db4"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "098d5034ca668638",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "d67de8615ea3d3a0",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "1",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": "1",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "true",
    "payloadType": "bool",
    "x": 130,
    "y": 240,
    "wires": [
        [
            "ad9334b7892cf503"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "0a6681231f307f16",
    "type": "http in",
    "z": "d67de8615ea3d3a0",
    "name": "",
    "url": "/testcase",
    "method": "get",
    "upload": false,
    "swaggerDoc": "",
    "x": 150,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": [
        [
            "ad9334b7892cf503"
        ]
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: What have you already tried? This is not a Node-RED problem, this is a basic dynamic webpage problem, the template node is just a way to serve a HTML page, it will ONLY be rendered when the page is loaded, if you want it to be dynamic you will need to code something in the page to retrieve the values as they change.

Comment: In the flow script provided inside the <script></script> there is the dynamic content function I have tried. It already shows dynamic change of seconds generated there. But when the with the variable generated in the code in the function node it does not work automatically (need to update the page). Have you tried the flow?

Comment: Edit the question to break out the HTML in the template, as it is it's impossible to read. And no I haven't loaded some random persons flow into my Node-RED instance, that would not be a smart thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Template nodes do not create a tunnel to the browser to push updates, they just render the template against the input once (they may not even ever be connected to a HTTP request)

The template will only be rendered once, on the HTTP request, and then be sent to the web browser.

When it is rendered all the variables will be replaced their values.

The inject node is not doing anything useful, because it will send the re-rendered template to the http-response node, which will just discard it, because it has already sent the first version to the browser and closed the connection.

If you want to dynamically update the page, you will need to create a second http endpoint and server up the dynamic values as a JSON object and have the script in the page make a HTTP request to the second endpoint, retrieve the JSON and then use that to update the page.